# How to stop result of function showing in Command Prompt

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

I have the below code in Powershell which brings the Command Prompt Window back to the foreground while running a script.  This works just fine, but it returns "True" in the Command Prompt window each time.  Is there a way to hide/remove this without using cls?

```
Add-Type -Name Window -Namespace Console -MemberDefinition '
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow);
'
function Show-Console {
    $consolePtr = [Console.Window]::GetConsoleWindow()
    [Console.Window]::ShowWindow($consolePtr, 9)
}
Show-Console
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call your function like that:

```
Show-Console | Out-Null
```

Comment: Or put a `[Void]` in front of `[Console.Window]::ShowWindow($consolePtr, 9)` or the `| Out-Null` behind, so it's internal to the function.